# Showing notification for new messages

Tags: php, mysql, sql, facebook

I have two tables `messages` and `thread` I am displaying new messages in inbox from `messages` table. If conversation is started I would like to show `1 new message` just like the way Facebook does. When you start a conversation and it shows 1 new, 2 new... The code I have below doesn't show. It gives me `undefined index thread_id`

What I want is if the `id` of the `messages` table match the `thread_message_id` of `thread` table, show number of unread messages for each row in the `messages` table. As on the below image(I just put `1 NEW` myself), I want to show the number of unread messages for each row.
[image: Here is the image] Does anyone have any idea?

```
$stmt = $msg->prepare(
"SELECT id, to_user, from_user, message, is_read, date, subject, orig_sender, conversation
FROM (
SELECT m.id, max(t.thread_id) thread_id,  m.to_user, m.from_user, m.message, m.is_read, m.date, m.subject, m.orig_sender, m.conversation
FROM messages m
LEFT JOIN thread t on(t.thread_message_id = m.id)
WHERE ( m.to_user = ?  
AND m.deleted != ?
AND m.del2 != ?)
OR
(m.from_user = ? 
AND m.conversation = 'true'
AND m.deleted != ?
AND m.del2 != ?) 
GROUP BY m.id
ORDER BY m.conversation asc, thread_id desc
) tbl");
 echo $msg->error;
 $stmt->bind_param('sss....', $username......);
 $stmt->execute();

 //I did new select query to get the thread_message_id 
 $thread = $msg->prepare("SELECT * FROM thread where thread_to_user = ? and thread_is_read = '0'");
 echo $msg->error;
 $thread->bind_param('s', $username->username );
 $thread->execute();
 $thread_unread = $thread->get_result();
 while ($row = $thread_unread->fetch_assoc()) {
 $thread_id = $row['thread_message_id'];
 }
while ($row = $max->fetch_assoc()) {


if($thread_id == $row['id'] && $thread->num_rows > 0){echo "<div class='m_new'>".$thread->num_rows."&nbsp;New"."</div>";}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to update instantly your page , you have to use Ajax . 
The idea is to make a first request as you did and store the result in a variable on the client side using Javascript/jquery and set a Nseconde refresh interval and get the result (using ajax) , store it in another new variable and compare them .
If its not the same ,update your message number . Else leave it as it is .
Hope that helps.

Comment: I don't to update instantly, I just want to show the unread messages related to the parent id on page refresh.